# What times what equals something?

Tags: soft-question

I wanted to find `x` times `y` equals to `z`, where `z` can be anything (Full number).

What I wanted :
I can say, I want to find what `x` times `y` equals to `65`.
The answer is `13` times `5`.
Now, I wanted that `65` or `z` to be anything.

I've found this site : https://researchmaniacs.com/Calculate/WhatTimesWhat/What-Times-What-Equals.html which does exactly that but unfortunately it only allows up to 5 digits number and the mechanics on how it works was not shown.

Comment: They just find all divisors of $z$. You can easily google an algorithm on how to do that